# Can't able to disconnect passed Audio element from disposed MediaElementAudioSource

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api

I've been trying to integrate HTML5 Audio with Web Audio. I'm using `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` to use HTML5 Audio. After some point of time I need to disconnect the HTML5 Audio completely from the connected `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` and may be need to connect with some other new `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` but when I try this I'm getting some error in Chrome not tested in other browsers though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being able to disconnect a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` is a [bug in the spec.](https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1202)

That you can't connect the HTML element to another `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` is a bug in Chrome.

I think the workaround is to use a `GainNode` to silence the node as needed.  Also use the fan-out capabilities of a audio node to route the output of the `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` to a new part of the graph as needed.  (Possibly inserting another gain node to allow control of the output.)

Not great, but workable, I think.